# How to add a custom favicon to sails.js application?

Tags: javascript, sails.js, favicon

`Sails.js` app uses a default favicon from express. I want to replace it with my own one but have struggled with it for a couple of hours.

I have tried to add a separate `favicon.js` with following code under config folder, but without luck.

```
/**
* favicon.ico
*/
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  express: {
    customMiddleware: function(app){
      console.log('loading favicon.'); //executed
      app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'icon_fav.ico')));
      app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        console.log("installed customMiddleware is used");
        next();
      })
    }
  }

};
```

By the way, adding following line in the view template will work in both Chrome and Fire Fox, but not in Safari (OSX), don't know why.

```
<link rel="icon" href="/img/icon_fav.png" type='image/png'>
```

Also tried to put `/favicon.ico` under web server root.

Googled for this, and it seems no one asked before.
Can someone point me to a solution?

Comment: Did you clear your cache after changing .ico ?

Comment: @BatuZet, yes, I did.

Answer (score 3):

What i did to update the favicon is put a version behind it.

```
<link rel="icon" href="/img/icon_fav.png?version=2" type="image/png">
```

Answer (score 2):

Put icon in root folder and use:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: I know this, and it should generally work, and it does so for Chrome and Firefox even when working with [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) and `angular.js`. But my such an app can't display favicon on OSX Safari (don't know why!!). However, an empty sail.js app created by `sails new clean_project` can work well with Safari when inserting such line (even favicon.ico is not under root, or has the default name). Another finding is http://localhost:1337/favicon.ico will always return the default express icon. I think there is something wrong with `sails.js`.

Comment: btw, link element in HTML doesn't have a closing tag, especially a convenience closing tag like "/>" is not suggested for HTML, in my opinion.

Comment: It's usually being cached pretty hard, but going to http://localhost:1337/favicon.ico and hitting Ctrl+R should do the fix.

Answer (score 0):

sail 0.12 actually serves it from public/favion.ico (although the boostrapped framework stores in it assets , and the documentation says it is at [assets/favicon.ico](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/anatomy/assets/favicon.ico)